# What is an elegant way to express $(-1)^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

In computation of series, a lot of times you will find a term $(-1)^k$ jutting out in an otherwise easy to remember expression.

Is there some interesting way to write $(-1)^k$ that may help in tidying up the expression or memorization?

Comment: I'd generally just read it as a notation for "alternates signs" if I want to remember something. Symbollicly, It doesn't exactly simplify to anything easier to remember.

Comment: There are other ways to write it but I think none is as compact or requires less parsing. E.g. $\cos(k\pi)$

Comment: Hm $i^{2k}$ seems shorter..

Comment: $(-1)^k$ is about as elegant and compact as you can get.  It just means alternately sum on every even steps, subtract on the odd ones.

Comment: $-^k$, which means $\underbrace{-\circ-\circ\ldots\circ-}_k$, where $-:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is the unary $-$ operator seems even shorter! Usage: $(-1)^k x=-^k x$.

Comment: Note that "tidy" is a subjective matter, and hence is not a good fit for a question here. "Help memorization" is borderline subjective too. The question in the title is also subjective. I recommend you improve the question.

Comment: That might even be a very old way to write it.